# Preference Activity get boolean in other activity

Tags: android

I have a PreferenceActivity and I want to get a pref value into an another activity.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="use_english"
    android:title=""
    android:summary=""
    android:defaultValue="false" />
```

And I want to get the boolean into my MainActivity.
How I am supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply call the following lines:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean mValue = sp.getBoolean("use_english", false);
```

**Note:** The first paramter is obviously the key specified in your Preferences-XML file. The second paramter is the default value. You can read more about this in the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Comment: do I have to do something like `use_english = sp.getBoolean("use_english", false);`

Comment: Yeah if you wanna save the value temporarily in a variable you should do it this way. (Just edited my answer to make it more clear)